# How to solve a system of integral equations?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have a system of two integral equations

```
Sin[v] Integrate[
     (x[v, z] b Sin[v])/Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[v]^2 + b^2 Sin[v]^2 + z^2)^3],
     {v, 0, 2Pi}, {z, -l, l}] == 0

Cos[v] Integrate[
    (x[v, z] a Cos[v])/Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[v]^2 + b^2 Sin[v]^2 + z^2)^3],
    {v, 0, 2Pi}, {z, -l, l}] == 0
```

I would like to find a solution  `x[v,z]` of the both equations.

Then I would like to plot 3D graph with axes `v,z,x[v,z]`.

Can anyone help me in finding a solution?

Comment: Cos and Sin are case sensitive cos[x] and sin[x] wont do anything.  I updated the code in your post

Comment: I'm confused by the region of integration `{z,-z,z}`, could you double check this?

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many solutions satisfying the system of the equations.
If we set `x[v, z]` to be constant and add appropriate assumptions the both integrals vanish.
Moreover we could find a few consecutive values of the integrals for e.g. `x[v, z] == z^k`
and `k ∈ {0, 1, 2, ...}` putting it in a `Table`.
Nevertheless we can do much more proving an appropriate theorem:

> If  `x[v, z]` doesn't depend on `v` and it is a polynomial function in `z` then the both integrals vanish.

To get this result let's check

```
Resolve[ 
  ForAll[ k, k ∈ Integers && k >= 0, 
          Integrate[ z^k Cos[v]/Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[v]^2 + b^2 Sin[v]^2 + z^2)^3], 
                     {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, -l, l}, 
                     Assumptions -> l > 0 && (a | b) ∈ Reals] == 0]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

similarly

```
Resolve[ 
  ForAll[ k, k ∈ Integers && k >= 0, 
          Integrate[ z^k Sin[v]/Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[v]^2 + b^2 Sin[v]^2 + z^2)^3], 
                     {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, -l, l}, 
                     Assumptions -> l > 0 && (a | b) ∈ Reals] == 0]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Since integration operator is linear  we have proved that for any polynomial `p[z] == x[v, z]` the both integrals vanish. QED.

Calulation of the integrals if `x[v, z]` depends on `v` only is much more involved and we could find its values on a case by case basis. If `x[v, z] == v z` the system is satisfied under assumptions `l > 0 && (a | b) ∈ Reals`.

Let's plot a few special cases of given functions

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2}, 
  GraphicsRow @ Table[
    Plot3D[ v z^k Cos[v]/Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[v]^2 + b^2 Sin[v]^2 + z^2)^3], 
            {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, -2, 2}, ClippingStyle -> None], {k, 0, 2}]]
```

[image]