# Can Mathematica solve integro-differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have integro-differential equations like this:

```
γ = 0.1;
κ = 0.15;
g = 0.2;
δ = 0.2 + 0.6 I;

eqns = {
   x'[t] == -γ x[t] - g Re@z[t],
   y'[t] == -κ y[t] + g Re@z[t],
   z[t] == 
    Integrate[(x[τ] - 
        y[τ]) Exp[ -δ (t - τ)], {τ, 0, t}]
   };

ints = {
   x[0] == 1,
   y[0] == 0
   };

NDSolve[Join[eqns, ints], {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I don't know how to use *Mathematica* to solve it or if it can be solved at all using some
combinations of built-in functions?

To solve integro-differential equations in *Mathematica* is important to me for studying some special physical models.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/how-to-plot-and-solve-the-numerical-solution-of-a-integro-differential-equation

Comment: Solving integral equations is hard enough. In general there is no systematic approach. Look e.g. here: [How to solve system of integral equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33055/how-to-solve-system-of-integral-equations/33059#33059) how one can get a general idea of possible solutions. There is no built-in functionality in any computer system for solving inegro-differential equations as far as I can say.

Comment: Also might want to check responses to similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974929/how-can-i-reference-a-specific-point-of-my-function-inside-ndsolve/6986001#6986001)

Answer (score 1):

For your special problem, it seems you can differentiate the third equation and transform it  into the differential equation `x[t] - y[t] - δ z[t]==z'[t]`. You can also deduce boundary conditions from the integral equation (compute `z[0]`).

Comment: Hi Ahmed, welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post. I edited the formatting of your answer as per the [guide found on the help centre](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). It's a good idea to read the guide and the [about page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/about)