# Nonlinear vibration

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, integral-equations

I am trying to solve this equation:[image: equation]

with the following constants:

```
alpha1=3.7
alpha2=3.84
Nnon=0.0009
Cnon=0
VDC=2
VAC=0.6
```

The solution should be as shown in the figure:
[image: solution]

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you have anything you've tried?

Comment: what you have is an integro-differential equation.  I dont believe there is any direct way to solve but start here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33791/2079

Comment: We already have several posts about this type of integro-differential equation. Start from here (don't miss the links in that post): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160639/1871

Comment: @Pillsy not really. Thanks george207 and xzczd for the links.